# Railscasts incompatibility with Rails 3? Need help debugging

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ruby-on-rails-3

I saw some comments in [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) that the solution does not work for Rails 3 and jQuery, but it's just not clear. This is the error I get in my console.:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: add_fields is not defined
(anonymous function)485:98
onclickd
```

It points to this link which is really long and weird: `<a href="#" onclick="add_fields(this, 'comment_titles', '&amp;lt;p class=\&amp;quot;fields\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;\n&amp;lt;label for=\&amp;quot;video_comment_titles_attributes_new_comment_titles_title\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Comment Title:&amp;lt;\/label&amp;gt;    \n&amp;lt;input id=\&amp;quot;video_comment_titles_attributes_new_comment_titles_title\&amp;quot; name=\&amp;quot;video[comment_titles_attributes][new_comment_titles][title]\&amp;quot; size=\&amp;quot;30\&amp;quot; type=\&amp;quot;text\&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;\n&amp;lt;input id=\&amp;quot;video_comment_titles_attributes_new_comment_titles__destroy\&amp;quot; name=\&amp;quot;video[comment_titles_attributes][new_comment_titles][_destroy]\&amp;quot; type=\&amp;quot;hidden\&amp;quot; value=\&amp;quot;false\&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href=\&amp;quot;#\&amp;quot; onclick=\&amp;quot;remove_fields(this); return false;\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;remove&amp;lt;\/a&amp;gt;\n&amp;lt;input id=\&amp;quot;add_comment_title\&amp;quot; name=\&amp;quot;commit\&amp;quot; type=\&amp;quot;submit\&amp;quot; value=\&amp;quot;Add\&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;\n    &amp;lt;div class=\'hint\'&amp;gt;Let your listeners know what comments you want by adding a guiding title for them. Pose a question, ask for feedback, or anything else!&amp;lt;\/div&amp;gt;\n&amp;lt;\/p&amp;gt;'); return false;">New Comment Title</a>`

It is this this link in my video show view:

```
<%= link_to_add_fields "New Comment Title", f, :comment_titles %>
```

This is the link_to_add_fields method in my application helper:

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)  
  new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new  
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|  
    render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)  
  end  
    link_to_function(name, h("add_fields(this, '#{association}', '#{escape_javascript(fields)}')"))  
end
```

This is the add fields function in my application.js:

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {  
        var new_id = new Date().getTime();  
        var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");  
        $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));  
    }
```

I pretty much copy and pasted from the railscast so I'm not sure what's going on.

How can I fix this? What other code would you like to see?

Comment: Your problem seems to be in your application.js So fix it and you can call you add_fields method after.

Answer (score 3):

So it seems like:

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {  
    var new_id = new Date().getTime();  
    var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");  
    $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));  
}
```

had to be outside of the of the document.ready() block.

Comment: This is because add_fields is not an anonymous function. It is applied on the on click of the link before the document is ready.